# PromiseKit unseen type conversion for NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, promisekit

I'm attempting to fetch a json from my path. And everything seems right (granted I came from Swift 2 and tried updating to Swift 4) however, things seem to have gone awry.

```
class func getPlayerStatuses(sportName: String) -> Promise<[NSDictionary]> {
    let path = "api/sports/player-status/\(sportName)/"
    return API.get(path).then { (json: NSDictionary) -> [NSDictionary] in
        let playerUpdates: [NSDictionary] = try json.get("player_updates")
        return playerUpdates
    }
}
```

And I'm receiving the following error.

```
Cannot convert value of type '(NSDictionary) throws -> [NSDictionary]' to expected argument type '(_) throws -> _'
```

Does anyone have any clues as to why I'm getting errors about type conversion?

Comment: What version of PMK you use?

Comment: @pacification PromiseKit version 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of returning non-promise value changed in [PMK 6](http://promisekit.org/news/2018/02/PromiseKit-6.0-Released/) (see `Why PromiseKit 5/6?` section). Now you should use `map` instead of `then` for this kind of work.